# MQTT payload parsing in Python

Tags: python, parsing, binary, mqtt, paho

I am using Paho library to receive MQTT data. I saved the data in a file. The data in the file reads:

```
EP]�gr:G�2D��?G��D0uG�:G`�D�龹�:G�9D����R��A[[B���A�@ZBʟ�A��ZB"j�AʆYBIC�B�A��A���BM���ffNk>>>]
```

In binary format, it converts to:

```
b'<<<[\x16\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb8PG\x00\x90\xdeE-&4\x90\x99\x03\x00\x00\x00\x0fQG\x000\xf0E\x9d\x89\x98\xe7\xbf\x03\x00\x00\x00tQG\x00\x90\xe6E\xbd`Kq\xbc\x03\x00\x00\x00BQG\x00\xd8\xf5E\xdb\x11\x82\xcb\xb9\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00B\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@B\x00\x00\x88A:f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa1J\xb1A\xbc\xee+B:\xc6\xe9Ad\xc9\xe3A*+\xd2A\xe7|\x07B\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00dBff.A\x00\x00\xf4A\xcb\xa1\x8bA\xcf\xf7\x9cBMUUwe\xf5\x17\x00\x00\xd8\xc0>>>]'
```

I am unable to understand the format of this data. Is there anyway to convert this to ASCII or utf-8 format or any other readable format?

Am I doing something wrong in receiving the data?
My receive callback function is as follows:

```
def on_message(client, userdata, message):

    f = open("test.txt","wb")
    f.write((message.payload))
    f.close()
    print("message received " ,message.payload)
    print("message topic=",message.topic)
    print("message qos=",message.qos)
    print("message retain flag=",message.retain)
```

Comment: We can't answer this, you need to ask who ever is publishing the data what format it is in.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm if I am using the mqtt library correctly. Is there some other way I can use paho to get the data in some other decipherable format?

Comment: the payload is just a byte array, how you choose to interpret that is entirely up to you. If you want to try `.decode('utf-8')` you can, but given the byte representation it's not going to help. You need to ask the publisher what the format is.

Answer (score 0):

message.payload.decode() Is what your looking for

Comment: The last comment under the question explains why this isn't the correct answer